# What are the best practices to transform a Wordpress live site to a PWA

Tags: wordpress, web, progressive-web-apps

What are the best practices to transform a Wordpress live website into a Progressive Web Application, is there a good plugin that is sufficient? How does it work? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: This is a recommendation question, too broad AND opinion based...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the WordPress RestAPI and a JS app for the frontend.
You have nice examples using React or Vue for the frontend and WordPress for the backend.

Comment: Ages ago I did Flash frontends with WP backends. Can you link to some Vue or React examples or articles about it? Thx!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/srhise/nuxt-wordpress-pwa